# When Copy + Pasting in Windows Explorer, Can I Immediately Edit the Filename Instead of Having "- Copy"?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I often copy and paste a file into the same folder (quickly pressing Ctrl+C, then Ctrl+V).

It seems the default Windows behaviour is to rename the duplicate file as "*filename* - Copy.*extension*".

Instead, I'd like to have the duplicate file immediately "ask" for a new name - have the rename box grab focus so I can rename the file and avoid conflict.

Is this possible?

Comment: Should be possible with a custom AutoHotkey script, but it'll have to be kept running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, F2

That's what I do.  For when you copy from a different folder this doesn't look like it's possible out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Karan](https://superuser.com/questions/912552/when-copy-pasting-in-windows-explorer-can-i-immediately-edit-the-filename-ins/1775438#comment1227586_912552) for the AutoHotkey idea in the comment to the question.

The following script gets the filename from the currently selected file in Explorer, shows a message box to enter the new name and then creates a copy of the file. I haven't tested what happens if you select multiple files. Adapt to your needs:

```ahk
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0-
#Warn
#SingleInstance

#HotIf WinActive("ahk_exe explorer.exe")

^q::DuplicateFile(GetSelectedFilePaths())

GetSelectedFilePaths() {
    winClass := WinGetClass( "ahk_id" . hWnd := WinExist("A"))
    if (winClass ~= "Progman|WorkerW|(Cabinet|Explore)WClass") {
        shellWindows := ComObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        if (winClass ~= "Progman|WorkerW")
            shellFolderView := shellWindows.Item( ComObject(VT_UI4 := 0x13, SWC_DESKTOP := 0x8) ).Document
        else {
            for window in shellWindows
                if (hWnd = window.HWND) && (shellFolderView := window.Document)
                    break
        }
        result := ""
        for item in shellFolderView.SelectedItems
            result .= (result = "" ? "" : "`n") . item.Path
        if !result
            result := shellFolderView.Folder.Self.Path
    } else {
        ClipSave := ClipboardAll
        Clipboard := ""
        SendInput "^c"
        ClipWait 2
        result := Clipboard
        Clipboard := ClipSave
    }
    Return result
}

DuplicateFile(Source, Overwrite := false) {
    SplitPath Source, &name, &dir, &ext, &name_no_ext, &drive

    IB := InputBox("Please enter the new name:", "Duplicate file", "w200 h80", name_no_ext)
    if IB.Result = "OK"
        FileCopy Source, dir "\" IB.Value "." ext, Overwrite
}
```

I got the code for the explorer script from [the AutoHotkey forum](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=60403), but adapted it to v2.

While this hasn't been the question, also notice that it is possible to change the default rename template (i.e. the "- Copy"), editing `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\NamingTemplates\CopyNameTemplate` (String) in the registry. The default is `%s - Copy`, where `%s` is the old name. This is described [here](https://winaero.com/change-the-copied-file-name-template-in-windows-10/).